# Call Intent.ACTION_DIAL from a Tab layout

Tags: android, audio, android-2.2-froyo, standby

How can we call Intent.ACTION_DIAL from a tab layout?

My code is:

```
 Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab


    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    
        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("contacts")
            .setIndicator("Contacts",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_contacts))
            .setContent(intent);
            
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

But the app showing an exception

```
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.android.contacts (with uid 10000) to be run in process org.sipdroid.sipua (with uid 10032)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo(ActivityThread.java:2330)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2558)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-14 14:08:21.024: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(543):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 14:08:21.063: WARN/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity org.sipdroid.sipua/.ui.SIPTabWidget
07-14 14:08:21.683: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43f7d678 org.sipdroid.sipua/.ui.SIPTabWidget}
07-14 14:08:27.443: DEBUG/dalvikvm(255): GC_EXPLICIT freed 93 objects / 4104 bytes in 135ms
07-14 14:08:32.106: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{43f7d678 org.sipdroid.sipua/.ui.SIPTabWidget}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The intent works fine when  I called startActivity() directly from setOnTabChangedListener.

Here is my code:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("dial")
    .setIndicator("Dialler", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_dial))
    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

and on Tab change I give:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        System.out.println(" Tab ID:  "+tabId);
        
        if(tabId.equals("dial")){
            intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            startActivity(intent);
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                    }   }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have the same problem like this guy: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg14856.html

You can not use code from other applications in your own, unless it has the same UserID. The mailinglists mentions tricking it with a SharedUserID (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#userid), but I doubt this will work.

All in all I would state it is not possible, unless you give the application root access.

Comment: >unless you give the application root access
Really?
I tried to do the same thing as jennifer and with root granted (with Runtime.getRuntime
().exec("su");) but it didn't work. Am I asking for root incorectly?